# Number of $N$-size configurations of coins to total a specific sum

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have a bunch of coins with denominations $d_1, d_2,\ldots,d_n$ and a target sum $M$. Is it possible to count the total number of ways I can select exactly $N$ coins (with replacement) that add up to $M$?

For example, if the denominations are $0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.50$ and the total $M = 0.75$, there are 12 permutations of $N = 3$ coins that total to $M$.

If possible, I would prefer to count the number of permutations, but combinations are acceptable as well.

I understand this is a dynamic programming problem but I was wondering if there's a way of counting the number of solutions.

I have found several related questions such as [fixed sum combinations]{[Fixed sum of combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585712/fixed-sum-of-combinations/585726)} and [number of ways to select a sum with limited number of elements]{[Number of ways to select a sum with limited number of elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594643/number-of-ways-to-select-a-sum-with-limited-number-of-elements)} but there are some differences.

Comment: Does it help that the dynamic programming solution can be adapted to also count the number of solutions?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am interested in alternative, non dynamic programming solutions but yes, thank you for making that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating functions can help. Specifically:

$$ f(x) = (x^{d_1} + x^{d_2} + ... + x^{d_m})^N $$

where the exponents $ d_1, d_2, ..., d_m$ are the denominations, $N$ is the size of configuration (number of coins to be used), and (after expanding) the coefficient of $x^M$ represents the number of configurations of $N$ coins that add to $M$.